# Boolean function confusion

Tags: boolean-expression

I'm trying to do the Kmap for `F(A,B,C,D)= A’B’C’D’+AC’D’+B’CD’+A’BCD+BC’D` . I'm getting a little confused because not all the variable groupings have the same number of variables. some have 4 and some have 3. is this equivalent to `F(A,B,C,D) = F(0,2,4,5,7)` ?  I don't know if you have to do something extra if theres a variable missing. like in the 2nd grouping `(AC'D')` theres no B. so do we have to do something to compensate for the missing term or is this just 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where those numbers `0,4,2,5,7` are coming from, a Karnaugh map (assuming that's what you meant) simply specifies the truth output for given inputs.

If a term is *missing,* then it has no effect on the outcome so *either* of its two possible values will affect the truth output. So, in essence, the following two expressions are identical:

```
AC'D' <=> A(B)C'D' + A(B')C'D'
```

If *more* than one term is missing, then you simply allow for *more* than two possibilities (`2n`, where `n` is the number of missing terms). So `A` would also be:

```
ABCD + ABCD' + ABC'D + ABC'D' + AB'CD + AB'CD' + AB'C'D + AB'C'D'
```

(`A` matched against the `23 = 8` possibilities for the `B`, `C` and `D` variables).

Hence the map for your particular function:

```
A'B'C'D' + AC'D' + B'CD' + A'BCD+BC'D
```

would be, for term one `A'B'C'D'`:

```
   AB:00 01 10 11
CD:00  T  .  .  .
   01  .  .  .  .
   10  .  .  .  .
   11  .  .  .  .
```

or'ed with term two `AC'D'`, equivalent to `ABC'D + AB'C'D`:

```
   AB:00 01 10 11
CD:00  .  .  T  T
   01  .  .  .  .
   10  .  .  .  .
   11  .  .  .  .
```

or'ed with term three `B'CD'`, which expands to `AB'CD + A'B'CD`:

```
   AB:00 01 10 11
CD:00  .  .  .  .
   01  .  .  .  .
   10  T  .  T  .
   11  .  .  .  .
```

and, finally, or'ed with term four `BC'D`, equal to `ABC'D + A'BC'D`:

```
   AB:00 01 10 11
CD:00  .  .  .  .
   01  .  T  .  T
   10  .  .  .  .
   11  .  .  .  .
```

Combining all these gives you:

```
   AB:00 01 10 11
CD:00  T  .  T  T
   01  .  T  .  T
   10  T  .  T  .
   11  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: i got 4 from converting the AC'D' into 100 which is 4. hmm not sure how i understand how to handle the 3 variable groups. im trying to figure out how to fill in my Kmap chart. and for AC'D' i just assumed it was 4 , and put it in in m4. kinda weird that i cant find any examples like this lol

Comment: i got it now , so everytime its missing a variable like that , there will be 2 cases of of that number  which correspond to what ever letter is missing compliment and non compoliment. thank you!!!

Comment: @johnturley, that's exactly right. In a two variable case (`A` and `B`), the expression `A` is identical to `AB + AB'`. In your case, `AC'D'` is not 4, it's actually both 8 (`AB'C'D'`) _and_ 12 (`ABC'D'`).

Answer (score 0):

A term with 3 variables just means that it covers 2 cells in the Karnaugh map.

```
  AB  00  01  11  10
CD
00    XX      YYYYYY
01
11
10
```

So XX is A'B'C'D' and YYYYYY is AC'D'.
The point in AC'D' is that the value of B is irrelevant, so it can be 1 or 0, so there are 2 cells.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Where the variables are missing call the `don't care` condition. If you are making a truth table for the expression, you don't care if the variables can take both 0 or 1 as per reduce the expression. Or use X (cross) for them